# Convert docx to Rmarkdown

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, pandoc

My workflow looks involves producing Microsoft Word reports (using Rmarkdown) containing analysis of data. These reports are then reviewed and commented using Word's call-out comments feature. It's easier to make edits addressing the comments within the Word document, so that's what I do. I would now like to carry over these changes onto the Rmarkdown document. How can I do this?

Can I convert docx to Rmarkdown directly? I'm aware I can convert docx to markdown using Pandoc.

Comment: not sure what's the difference between rmarkdown and pandoc markdown, but you could probably write a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html) to make the necessary changes. Regarding importing word corrections, use the `--track-changes` flag.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of converting from a .docx Word file to R markdown, and then to HTML.

```
require(rmarkdown);require(devtools)
examplefile=paste0(tempdir(),"/example.docx")
download.file("https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/file-sample_100kB.docx",destfile=examplefile)
pandoc_convert(examplefile,to="markdown",output = "example.rmd", options=c("--extract-media=."))

render(paste0(tempdir(), "/example.rmd"),"html_document")
browseURL(paste0(tempdir(),"/example.html"))
```

Comment: How can we retain the formatting in the `.docx`?

Comment: Has this been outdated by the URL failing? Can someone update it?