# Word to R Markdown Conversion

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown

I have received a file stored in Microsoft Word that includes formatted words (italics, bold).  I would like to do some work with the file (extracting sections, inserting words, etc.) and was planning to do this work with R Markdown.  I need to keep the formatting (italics, bold) from Word during this conversion.  I know I can convert from Markdown to Word, but is the reverse conversion from Word to Markdown also possible?  If not, does anyone have any suggestions of how to bring Word into Markdown (relatively) painlessly while maintaining the italics and bold formatting?

Comment: Found this on Google, have you tried it? https://word2md.com/

Comment: The [pandoc manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--from) says you can use a docx file as input. Have you tried that?

Comment: The word2md converter is interesting but doesn't work as well for my file as Pandoc does--thank you both for the suggestions!  I am going to try working with Pandoc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use first pandoc, then RStudio.

1. In pandoc, `pandoc -o output.md originFile.docx`. In which, your
   output is a markdown from a Word.
2. Open your RStudio, you can choose your type file at the bottom of the console, whether you select "markdown" or "Rmarkdown". You will be able to change your markdown file.

Also there is [Writeage](https://www.writage.com/), from convert markdown to word. This is a pulgin in Word

Answer (score 0):

From the pandoc manual under "Demos": pandoc -s example30.docx -t markdown -o example35.md

For rmarkdown, please see this answer, [Convert docx to Rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112567/convert-docx-to-rmarkdown)